# Create oracle read only user for ODBC

Tags: oracle

I have created a user on the oracle database using

```
create user xxx identified by test; 
grant create session to xxx;
grant select any table to xxx;
grant select any dictionary to xxx;
```

I have also set up an ODBC connection from Excel which works fine for user yyy, but when I try to do the same for xxx I get error: table or view does not exist.

so my question is, how do I get the tables to appear/ available for user xxx?

Appreciate your help.
Cheers

Comment: Sorry, just to be clear as well, user xxx should have read-only access to the database / tables.

Comment: Give more information, it may help you to get an answer. For example who is the owner of the table, from which user the GRANTS are invoked, does the table has a public synonym

Comment: @ThomasG - please explain how you think a connection "falls into the default schema (SYS).  First, there is no "default" schema, certainly not SYS, who holds the keys to the kingdom.  Second, when a user connects, he always "falls into" (strange terminology) his own schema, where all unqualified name references resolve to his own namespace.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I am very new to this setup and the first time I am trying this. I am creating user YYY with user XXX (which is called oracle in the DB). When I login as YYY i can see under user ORACLE all the tables in the database, but when I login as user YYY I cannot see any tables. @DesignerAnalyst I am not sure how to check the owner or whether or not it has a public synonym.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need create SYNONYM in schema XXX for the tables in schema YYY.

```
grant create synonym to XXX;
```

Run this SQL as user YYY.

```
select 'CREATE SYNONYM ' ||tname|| ' for  '||'YYY.'||TNAME||';'  from tab
where tname not like 'BIN$%'
```

for example, output this sql.

```
CREATE SYNONYM TEST2 for  YYY.TEST2;
CREATE SYNONYM TEST_ARCHIVE for  YYY.TEST_ARCHIVE;
CREATE SYNONYM TEST_ONLINE for  YYY.TEST_ONLINE;
```

Run this SQL as XXX

```
CREATE SYNONYM TEST2 for  YYY.TEST2;
CREATE SYNONYM TEST_ARCHIVE for  YYY.TEST_ARCHIVE;
CREATE SYNONYM TEST_ONLINE for  YYY.TEST_ONLINE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with synonyms is OK. The other option is change current schema

1. `grant alter session to xxx`
2. Log as xxx
3. After logon to db. `ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = yyy`

now each objets' name will be resolved under schema yyy

Comment: Or fully-qualify the name of the table, i.e. `SELECT * FROM YYY.SOME_TABLE` instead of `SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE`. In the first case OP would know precisely which table they're accessing.